# Generalization of Baby Rudin Chapter 2 Exercise 8

Tags: real-analysis

So the text of the question says

> Is every point of every open set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a limit point of $E$?

Now, I wanted to generalize my answer (which is yes). That is, for every open set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^k$. Now the proof for that is below, but the issue I have with it is that it seems to imply that for every open subset of a metric space (which I'm not sure is true) if I just replace a few things. I simply need to replace $\lvert a-x\rvert$ with $d(x,a)$ for $x \in X$ and $a\in X$where $X$ is some metric space with a metric $d$ (if that is wrong someone will tell me I'm sure). Hence, my question is: what's wrong with the proof? Keep in mind that I'm using Rudin's definitions, or, at least, as best as I understand them. Thanks in advance.

Anyway the proof:

Let $a \in E \subset \mathbb{R}^k$. Since $E$ is open, it follows that there exists some neighborhood $N_r(a)$ with radius $r>0$ of $a$ such that $N_r(a) \subset E$.

Now, consider $N_s(a)$ for some $s>0$.

We have two possibilities. Firstly that for an $s$, $N_s(a) \cap E=\emptyset$. Secondly that for an $s$, $N_s(a) \cap E \neq \emptyset$.

If, for at least one $s$, $N_s(a) \cap E = \emptyset$ then $a$ is not a limit point of $E$

Since $s$ is a real number, there are three possibilities for $s$.
Firstly, $s=r$.
Secondly, $s<r$.
Thirdly $s>r$.

If $s=r$ then $N_r (a)=N_s (a)$. Hence, since $N_r(a)⊂E$ then $N_s (a)∩E≠∅$

As for $s<r$.
Now, $N_r (a)=\{x:|a-x|<r\}$ and $N_s (a)=\{y:|a-y|<s\}$

Since $s<r$, it follows that for $∀y∈N_s(a), |a-y|<r$, since for $∀y∈N_s(a), |a-y|<s$.

Hence, $N_s (a)⊂N_r (a)$. Since $N_r (a)⊂E$, then $N_s (a)⊂E⇒N_s (a)∩E≠∅$.

As for $s>r$.
Now, $N_r (a)=\{x:|a-x|<r\}$ and $N_s (a)=\{y:|a-y|<s\}$

Since $r<s$, it follows that for $∀x∈N_s (a), |a-x|<s$, since for $∀x∈N_r (a) |a-x|<r$.

Hence, $N_r (a)⊂N_s (a)$. $N_r (a)⊂E$ and $N_r (a)⊂N_s (a)⇒E∩N_s (a)=N_r (a)∪A≠∅$ for some $A⊂R^k$.

Hence, for $∀s∈\mathbb{R}$, $N_s (a)∩E≠∅$.
Therefore, all neighborhoods of a contain a subset of $E$. Hence, a is a limit point of $E$. Hence, the answer is yes.

Comment: Possibly the question should read "Is every point of every open set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a limit point **of $E?$**

Comment: Actually, that's how he wrote it. I forgot to add that in.

Answer (score 1):

> If, for at least one $s$, $N_s(a) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ then $a$ is not a limit point of $E$

This is not a true statement.

A limit point requires that every neighborhood contains one point that is different from it. Hence if you consider the discrete metric space where a neighborhood can contain only one point, then we have a counterexample.

Comment: I have no idea what a discrete measure is, if you could explain it that it'd be great. And I corrected my mistake, I had mis-written it it was supposed to be written as "if, for at least one s, $N_s(a)∩E=∅$ then $a$ is not a limit point of $E$"

Comment: [Discrete metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space): Each neighborhood of radius less than $1$ only contain itself.